# How to access textbox values dynamically in MS access form 2013 VB Script

Tags: vbscript, ms-access-2013

I have 85 textboxes in my form of MS ACCESS 2013 with names *inc_1*, *inc_2*, *inc_3* and so on....

I need to retrieve the values of these textboxes by using a loop. (of course I cannot access all textboxes individually) something like below:

```
dim a(1 to 85)
for i = 1 to 85
     temp ="inc_" & i
     a(i) = me.temp.value
next
```

This is obviously not working.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: i am writing this code in forms backend vb script editor

Answer (score 1):

The line of code you need to use is

```vbs
a(i) = Me.Controls(temp).Value
```

Comment: @ShailendraBaranwal  You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer.  You and Gord will both get points.  More importantly other readers will know you have a solution for your question.